# Modifying an Android Libraries' package using gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, root

Is it, or would it be possible to modify a libraries' packagename at compile time using a gradle task similar to how jarjar works for changing the packagenames of a .jar file.

The library is pretty standard and included as follows:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.scottyab:rootbeer-lib:0.0.6'
}
```

The purpose of this would be to change the name to avoid static detection of the library by root cloaking apps.

Any advice or guidance much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Have you considered just not caring if the user is root?  Its my device, I can and should be able to use its full power.  And since root detection is hardly foolproof, its just giving you a false sense of security anyway.  If there's information you don't want a potential root user to have, it shouldn't ever be client side.

Comment: The `jarjar` tool can actually be used with `gradle`. Here's an [example](https://github.com/shevek/jarjar/blob/master/jarjar-gradle/example/build.gradle). Or are you trying to implement the same functionality in `groovy`?

Comment: @GabeSechan I'm not really interested in the politics of it. Some of my devices are rooted, and no one is trying to say what you can and cannot do with your device. But certain applications cannot help but contain sensitive information: email, banking apps, text messages. Granting root allows a process to do anything it wants, so you have to trust every single rooted process not be outright malicious and also not contain any security bugs.

Comment: @dev.bmax jarjar works on .jar files, what I'm looking to do is rename an android library package name.

Comment: Inside of yourLibrary.aar file there's a classes.jar file. So jarjar-gradle plugin might still be useful

Comment: @stealthcopter that's not what root means. Root does not mean you need to trust every process on the device. Because a rooted phone means the user can set a process as root, not that all apps are root. As for sensitive information- if you can't resist the user with the information, it shouldn't be on the client device at all. If you can, then root doesn't matter

Comment: @GabeSechan I didn't say that. I said you needed to trust every rooted process. And as I said it's not really about trusting the user with the information, most apps have data that is private to that user. It's malicious apps that are the problem, what if your SU binary actually decides to read your emails and upload them all to a server? As it has root there is nothing to stop it doing so and very little you can do to detect it.

Comment: @dev.bmax Yes, you're right. But then I would need something to do the same on any resources outside of the jar file. I was just hoping for a way to do it on an .aar

Comment: Usually, the only resource file, where a package name can be found is the manifest file (layout files can use relative class names). But during the build of your client's project, all manifests (app+libs) are merged into one, and your package name should not be in the final manifest. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @stealthcopter since the user would have to give that app root (it can't take it for itself), it is about trusting the user. What if I want to back up all my emails to the cloud, or run it through an app on my local device? I should be able to do that, and you shouldn't be preventing me. It's my info, I can do what I want with it.

Comment: @stealthcopter Basically, root doesn't matter-  ever.  If you're ok with the user having the information, then its ok to trust him with the information and root.  If you aren't ok with that, then it shouldn't live on the client device.  Preventing root provides no extra security, as a malicious user can do malicious things without root (trivially, he can backup his disk and get all the info).  All you do is make life harder on the user to use a device he has bought and paid for.  If I were you I'd delete the library and work on something useful.

Comment: @GabeSechan I disagree. It's not about trusting the user, it's about trusting the entire phone as a whole. Root is used by almost all malware on Android. If an app can detect root and protect some private user data from being stolen, then that's awesome. No, it's not going to be foolproof but it will help.
Of course in a perfect world you wouldn't store any private data on a users phone, but that isn't always an option (again think about emails on your device)

Comment: @stealthcopter I am thinking about the emails on the device.  And the fact that I use root based apps as a backup device.  You are limiting my options as the data owner.  That is NOT acceptable.  If you have information that YOU own that needs protecting, don't put it on the client.  If you have information that I own, then I have EVERY right to use root to access it as I want.  You completely misundersatnd the threat vector-  preventing root is about mistrusting users, not the device.

Comment: @stealthcopter As for malicious software-  they don't need a rooted phone.  They use flaws in android/linux to get root even when its not installed.  So you provide 0 extra security against them.  And if you're really worried about them-  the answer once again is not to store data on the client device.  You provide 0 benefit, and make life worse for the user.

Comment: @GabeSechan You're not listening to what I'm saying. This isn't about trusting the users, it's about trusting the entire phone and every rooted app on it. The threat isn't the users, no one cares (some companies prob do) if they have the data that they already own. It's about protecting it from being taken off the device without authorisation. I'm not here to take away your freedoms, I don't care if your phone is rooted or not. But if you don't want any root checking then you are totally free to not download any app that contains root checking code.

Comment: I am. You just don't understand what a threat vector is and how you address it. Malicious apps don't depend on a user rooting their phone. They find exploits that grant them root powers. You can't detect that. All you do is prevent a user from installing root for his own uses. Which provides zero help against  malicious apps

Comment: @GabeSechan There are malicious apps aimed at rooted phone users, and also other malicious apps install toolkits that this library can detect. It's not foolproof but it can help. This app doesn't prevent a user from installing root at all, it simply checks for it. You may want to enable / disable certain features of your app for root users, you may simply want to log it as a statistic to see how many users have root for your app. Developers should be free to do as they please. If it's your app you can write it however you want :)

Comment: It doesn't help. Any competent piece of malware can and does get root without needing it to be pre-installed. Your library neither prevents nor detected that. It's like drm- an idea everyone knows is broken and only makes life harder for legitimate users.  It's a negative in the world of software.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148515/discussion-between-stealthcopter-and-gabe-sechan).

Comment: I think the rootbeer library is great! thanks for putting in the effort to make it guys, keep up the good work! :-)

Comment: There is already a Gradle plugin that does something similar. It relocates dependencies. May be this could help [Shadow](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow).
Here is the article [http://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/](http://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a Gradle plugin that does something similar. It relocates dependencies, [Shadow](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow).

It bundles and relocates common dependencies in libraries to avoid classpath conflicts.Shadow uses the ASM library to modify class byte code to replace the package name and any import statements for a class. Any non-class files that are stored within a package structure are also relocated to the new location.

This is how you relocate a package:

```
shadowJar {
   relocate 'junit.framework', 'shadow.junit'
}
```

The code snippet will rewrite the location for any class in the junit.framework to be shadow.junit. For example, the class junit.textui.TestRunner becomes shadow.junit.TestRunner. In the resulting JAR, the class file is relocated from junit/textui/TestRunner.class to shadow/junit/TestRunner.class.

Answer (score 2):

There is already a Gradle plugin that does something similar. It relocates dependencies, [Shadow](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow).

It bundles and relocates common dependencies in libraries to avoid classpath conflicts.Shadow uses the ASM library to modify class byte code to replace the package name and any import statements for a class. Any non-class files that are stored within a package structure are also relocated to the new location.

This is how you relocate a package:

```
shadowJar {
   relocate 'junit.framework', 'shadow.junit'
}
```

The code snippet will rewrite the location for any class in the junit.framework to be shadow.junit. For example, the class junit.textui.TestRunner becomes shadow.junit.TestRunner. In the resulting JAR, the class file is relocated from junit/textui/TestRunner.class to shadow/junit/TestRunner.class.

Answer (score 0):

I can see the library you are using is an open source library. You can simply clone the repo from here https://github.com/scottyab/rootbeer
and modify it to use any name you want. You don't even need to build your changes as a aar library. Simply import it as a module in Android Studio.

Gradle tasks are very powerful as well and it should be possible to do it with gradle but I don't know how.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I am one of the authors of this library. I was hoping to create a gradle task to automate this for use by others.